# Calling a class method within a class

Tags: ruby

I realize this perhaps a naive question but still I cant figure out how to call one method from another in a Ruby class.

i.e. In Ruby is it possible to do the following:

```
class A
   def met1
   end
   def met2
      met1 #call to previously defined method1
   end
end
```

Thanks,

RM

Comment: Your example works quite right I would say (with something in met1).

Comment: it's possible, and it's done just like you did it :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Those aren't class methods, they are instance methods.  You can call met1 from met2 in your example without a problem using an instance of the class:

```
class A
   def met1
     puts "In met1"
   end
   def met2
      met1
   end
end

var1 = A.new
var1.met2
```

Here is the equivalent using class methods which you create by prefixing the name of the method with its class name:

```
class A
   def A.met1
     puts "In met1"
   end
   def A.met2
      met1
   end
end

A.met2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... for some reason i didnt work for me before