# Ruby On Rails: Can I call a class method from a class method?

Tags: ruby, class-method

I need to know if I can call a class method from a class method and how.

I've got a class on my model and one of my class methods is getting long:

```
def self.method1(bar)
  # Really long method that I need to split
  # Do things with bar
end
```

So I want to split this method in 2 methods. Something like that

```
def self.method1(bar)
  # Do things with bar
  # Call to method2
end

def self.method2(bar)
  # Do things
end
```

Both of them must be class methods

How can I call this **method2** from **method1**?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course you can do this call. Did you try it? Did you get an error? You might need to qualify it with `self.`: `self.method2(bar)`.

Comment: If they are inside a class you call normally method2(bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered here: [Calling a class method within a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336024/calling-a-class-method-within-a-class)

To re-iterate:

```
def self.method1(bar)
  # Do things with bar
  # Call to method2
  method2( bar )
end
```

A full class example:

```
class MyClass
  def self.method1(bar)
    bar = "hello #{ bar }!"
    method2( bar )
  end

  def self.method2(bar)
    puts "bar is #{ bar }"
  end
end

MyClass.method1( 'Foo' )
```

Answer (score 1):

For you to understand what is going on, you've got to check the scope inside the class method.

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts self
  end
end

Foo.bar
# => Foo
```

When `Foo.bar` is called, `Foo` is returned. Not an instance, but the class. That means you can access every class method of `Foo` inside the `self.bar` method.

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts "bar was called"
    self.qux
  end

  def self.qux
    puts "qux was called."
  end
end

Foo.bar
# => bar was called
#    qux was called.
```

Answer (score 1):

`self` in the context of the class method is the class itself. So can access every class method defined in the current class. Examples above are very useful but I want to give you another one which is a little bit more clear (in my opinion):

```
class MyClass
   def self.method1
     p self
     puts "#{method2}"
   end

   def self.method2
     puts "Hello Ruby World!\n I am class method called from another class method!"
   end
 end

MyClass.method1
# => MyClass

# => Hello Ruby World!
     I am class method called from another class method!
```